# view only one transparent object at viewport when overlaping to another object in blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

i used to do this using blender 2.79 version with no problem .
now i need to do the same work with the 2.8 version , but cant find the way
when i have two objects , one on top of the other , i need to see only through the object that is on top or front, without making the one that is behind transparent. I found the xray mode but it turns all objects on the scene transparent , and as i said , i need to see through the first one and the other needs to remain solid.

this is how i did with the 2.79 version, and now im using 2.8 but cant find how to do it

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### EEVEE

Use alpha **and** also change the setting of Blend Mode in that material:

[image]

[image]

The Blend option need to be set explicitly to make EEVEE know what material need to consider transparent problem. And only alpha blend will give an actual blend process for color.

#### Related post

- [Material Settings — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#blend-mode)
- [Transparent Materials Workflow from Cycles to EEVEE from 2.79 - General Forums / Blender Development Discussion - Blender Artists Community](https://blenderartists.org/t/transparent-materials-workflow-from-cycles-to-eevee-from-2-79/1129207)
- [How to use alpha transparent textures in Blender - Artisticrender.com](https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-alpha-transparent-textures-in-blender/)